# Excel merge comma separated cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two cells that are comma separated. They both contain the same amount of information. I need to merge them in the following format:

Cell 1: A,B,C,D,E

Cell 2: 1,2,3,4,5

Result: A,1,B,2,C,3,D,4,E,5

How could this be achieved?

Comment: @BhavyaGupta this question is fine for SuperUser, OP should really show his research effort and what they have tried, but there is nothing wrong with the over nature of this question

Comment: Ok, on your advice, I deleted the comment but Excel questions get better attention on StackOverflow.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta no they don't, go and see how many un-answered Excel questions you can find on here.....

Comment: @BhavyaGupta 3 answers in first hour isn't bad attention lol

Answer (score 1):

One step, One formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")&","&FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"))
```

FILTERXML creates arrays of the cell text and TEXTJOIN puts them together.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, so my answer reflects this.

A simple way of doing this would be to use text to columns to separate the vales, then add them together with a simple formula:

```
=A1&","&A2&","&B1&","&B2&","&C1&","&C2&","&D1&","&D2&","&E1&","&E2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your source data is in this format：

[image]

As far as I know, merging these two cells with a formula can't get the results you want. Generally they can only merge in this format:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,",",A2)
```

[image]

According to my research, you can't get results directly unless you use VBA.

I suggest you separate the cell first.

"Date" - "Text to column"

[image]

Then use the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(A8,",",A9,",",B8,",",B9,",",C8,",",C9,",",D8,",",D9,",",E8,",",E9)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the amount of comma separated variables is not constant. Is it possible to do a loop as a formula to get all of the comma separated variables.

Comment: @OleB Your question does not specify this detail, please edit your question to include as much detail as possible

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest a 2 step solution, where `step one` separates, comma separated values into multiple cells, and `step two` makes the desire combination:*

---

[image]

---

**Step 1:**
 - You need a UDF (User Define Function), a Macro.

```
    Function SplitValues(a As String, b As String)

    Dim Text() As String
    Text = Split(b, a)
    SplitValues = Text

    End Function
```

---

**How it works:**

- Press **Alt+F11** to open VB editor.
- From VB editor windows, select & **R**ight click `This Workbook` icon.
- Hit, **I**nsert then **M**odule.
- **C**opy & **P**aste this code.
- Press **Alt+Q** to return to Sheet, and save the workbook as Macro Enabled (`.xlsm`).
- In cell `B100` enter this formula.

`=SplitValues(",",A100)`

- Fill formula right, press `F2` and finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

*- Formula will looks like `{=SplitValues(",",A100)}`*

- Fill formula down for row `101`.

**For step 2:**

- Formula in cell `A103`:

  ```
   =SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(B100&" "&B101&" "&C100&" "&C101&" "&D100&" "&D101&" "&E100&" "&E101&" "&F100&" "&F101)," ",", ")
  ```

**If you are using higher version like Office 365 & others, then you may use this one also.**

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,B100,B101,C100,C101,D100,D101,E100,E101,F100,F101)
```

**N.B.** *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Public Function Knit(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String
    Dim s As String, L As Long, U As Long, i As Long

    arr1 = Split(s1, ",")
    arr2 = Split(s2, ",")
    L = LBound(arr1)
    U = UBound(arr1)

    For i = L To U
        s = s & IIf(s = "", "", ",") & arr1(i) & "," & arr2(i)
    Next i
    Knit = s
End Function
```

[image]